# The Shemen ha-Tov on the red heifer

Tags: sources-mekorot, chukas, parah-adumah

This article [cites](https://torah.org/torah-portion/ravfrand-5770-chukas/) a teaching of “the Shemen ha-Tov”. Can anyone help me find this source?
Many thanks.

Comment: It seems that the Shemen Hatov was written by Rav Shmuel Shmelka ben Tzvi Hirsch  Horowitz. This is the place in Hebrewbooks.org  - https://hebrewbooks.org/50691 but in a short time I did not find his discussion of the poroh adumah.

Comment: @יהושעק Specifically looking for this passage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reference is to Rabbi Dov Ze'ev Weinberger's Shemen Hatov, Parashat Chukat, pp. 286-287 (in Hebrew). Here's the quote:

> "זאת חקת התורה אשר צוה ה' לאמר וכו'. ברש"י לפי שהשטן ואומות העולם מונין את ישראל לומר מה המצוה הזאת ומה טעם יש בה לפיכך כתב בה חוקה גזירה היא מלפני שאין לך רשות להרהר אחרי, עכ"ל. ולכאורה למה צריך רש"י ליתן טעם למה היא חוקה, והלא כיון שאין לה טעם לכן היא חוקה, גם מבלי השטן ואומות העולם ומה זה לפיכך כתב בה חוקה; וגם אם האומות מונין מה התירוץ שנותנים להם חוקה חקקתי וכו'. ומוכח מדברי רש"י, דבאמת יש לה טעם לפרה אדומה, אלא שלא נתגלה לנו בהדיא. ואיתא במדרש (ילקוט שמעוני במדבר פרק יט רמז תשנ"ט): אמר שלמה על כל התורה כולה עמדתי ועל פרשה זו של פרה כיון שהייתי מגיע בה הייתי דורש בה חוקר בה ושואל בה אמרתי אחכמה והיא רחוקה ממני, מי כהחכם זה משה דכתיב ביה עיר גבורים עלה חכם וגו' יודע פשר דבר שפירש התורה לישראל.
>
> ובא ללמד, שלעולם צריך לקיים תורה ומצות לא מצד השכל המוגבל של האדם, אף במקום שנראה לו כי מבין טעם הדבר גם שם מבטל דעתו ועושה משום גזרה הוא מלפני וכו', והיינו דהטעם ניתן להבין רק לאחר שמקיים ע"פ גזירת חוקה חקקתי וכו', וכפי שכבר בארנו דביחוד בא הלימוד בעניין טהרה מטומאת מת, משום דכל עניין מיתה בעולם בא ע"י חטא דעץ הדעת והוא החשק לידע טוב ורע, כענין "והייתם כאלקים יודעי טוב ורע", ולכן בא הטהרה דוקא ע"י ביטול הדעת, ולא לעשות מצד השכל אלא בקבלת עול. וזהו מה שרמזו לדמא בן נתינה דדוקא ע"י פרה אדומה זכה לעשירות בשכר כיבוד אב שלו, להראות לו דהוא אינו משיג אלא מצוה שכלית אבל כלל ישראל מוכנים לשלם הון רב גם לקיום מצוה חוקית שלא מרגישים הטעם."

Comment: Thank you! Really helpfil

Comment: Is it this Shemen ha-Tov? https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001048494/NLI And if so is your page reference to the 4th volume, which I assume is B’midbar?

Comment: @Zarka yes, although volume 4 from what I recall has all of the parashot, not just Bamidbar. I don't know how the division works. Perhaps each volume is different chiddushim on all of the Torah.